# How many emails and accounts an organization's administrator and developer should have?

Tags: email, account-security, privileged-account, administration

Let's say there is a small organization called "Example" with the registered domain "example.com".

There is a person, Bob, who has full control over the organization's GitHub account. Bob also manages the organization's AWS account.

Bob also writes BAU code for this organization.

In order to follow the modern security standards, what should be the setup of Bob's emails and accounts?

Some example setups (not exhaustive, just to illustrate what I mean):

Example 1:

- 1 email bob@example.com
- 1 AWS account registered with this email used for admin and dev purposes
- 1 GitHub account registered with this email used for admin and dev purposes

Example 2:

- 1 email bob@example.com
- 2 AWS accounts:

  - 1 registered with bob@example.com used for admin purposes
  - 1 registered with alias bob-2@example.com for dev purposes
- 2 GitHub accounts: AWS-like arrangement

Example 3:

- 3 emails: bob_admin_github@example.com, bob_admin_aws@example.com, bob_dev@.example.com
- 2 AWS accounts:

  - 1 registered with bob_admin_aws@example.com for admin purposes
  - 1 registered with bob_dev@example.com for dev purposes
- 2 GitHub accounts:

  - 1 registered with bob_admin_github@example.com used for admin purposes
  - 1 registered with bob_dev@example.com for dev purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure that any modern security standards specify how many email accounts anyone should have

Comment: And I am not sure the number of email accounts of one company would make sense to every other company.